# Check if a number is int or float in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query in which I need to check if a number if an integer or float. There doesn't seem to be an easy way around to do this in Amazon Redshift.

> Would anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Something like `isint(<number>)` would be great.

Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I've resolved it this way. If after rounding a number, the resulting number keeps being equal to the original number, it's an integer; otherwise, it is not.

```
select

case
    when round(0.5, 0) = 0.5 then 'Not Integer'
    when round(1, 0) = 1 then 'Integer'
end as check
```

Answer (score -2):

The following:

```sql
SELECT pg_typeof(4);
```

returns `integer`, while for `4.5` it returns `numeric`.

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-info.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a Postgres function, not supported by Redshift.